# Как сделать плавное движение слова?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

как сделать что бы при нажатии на слово,оно плавно перемещалось над полоской. И так все остальные слова. Потом я нажимаю на "проверить" и если не правильно,то выдается ошибка,если правильно то выдается сообщение "верно"

```html
<button type="button" id="r">Проверить</button>

<div>Выберите слова,к которым при множественном числе добавляются -es</div>

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="600" height="130" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


  <line x1="100" x2="600" y1="100" y2="100" stroke="orange" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
  
</svg>

<div>an actress(актриса)</div>
<div>a dress(платье ) </div>
<div>wolf(волк) </div>
<div>a tomato (томат)</div>
<div>wife(жена) </div>



<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="600" height="130" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


  

<div id="rect"></div>
```

Comment: и и как узнать проверено или нет ? что значит проверка ?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, что Вы имели ввиду, то можно в обработке клика просто добавить к элементу класс, в котором будет указаны margin-left: 1em (допустим) и transition: .2s.
Это как пример:

```js
const block = document.getElementById('block');

block.addEventListener('click', () => {
  block.classList.add('slide');
});
```

```css
.slide {
  margin-left: 1em;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">Нажми на меня</div>
```

Comment: как будет выглядеть полностью весь код? Или куда вставлять ваш код?

Comment: @Юлий, html в index.html, css либо в <style>, либо в style.css, js либо в <script>, либо в script.js

Comment: @Юлий, весь код не знаю, я просто привёл пример как сдвинуть влево, по нему можно сделать так как нужно Вам. Первый кусок кода - js, второй - css, третий - html. Их вставлять в соответствующие файлы.